# Format cell A based on column L in that row not empty

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I want to format cell A in a row (each row is a different customer order) when there is a ship date present in column L. I have formatting to turn Column A yellow or red based on the target ship date and current date to keep things running smoothly.

If I can turn those cells green when they are shipped it would be easier to look at these on the production floor.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure a rule such as:

```
=L1>0
```

(assuming applied from A1 downwards) is at the top of the list.